# Set of all eigenvectors of matrix $A$ form a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I wanted to prove that the set of all eigenvectors of matrix $A$ form a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then we would have

$$\begin{cases}T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)= \lambda x+\lambda y = \lambda (x+y)\\T(cx)=cT(x) = c \lambda x\end{cases}$$

Is it this straightforward or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not true. Take the matrix $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,2)$. The set of all eigenvectors is $\operatorname{sp} \{ e_1 \}  \cup \operatorname{sp} \{ e_2 \}$ which is not a subspace. The mistake above is assuming that the eigenvalues are the same for different eigenvectors. For a specificy eigenvalue, the above shows that the set of all corresponding eigenvectors is a subspace.

Comment: You are confusing the definition of "linear transformation" with the definition of "subspace."  Furthermore, your statement "I wanted to prove that the set of all eigenvectors of matrix $A$ form a subspace of $R^{n}$" simply isn't true.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ eigenvectors corresponding to same eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. mathlover you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The set of eigenvectors corresponding to one of the eigenvalues of $A $, say $ \lambda$, is a subspace (called eigenspace of $A $ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$).

So your proof works but the statement of the result needs to be fixed as the set of all the eigenvectors of $A $ will in general not be a subspace (as pointed out in one of the comments).